# Kotlin Coroutines Correct Dispatcher Usage

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Do you think the following Dispatcher usage is correct? What is the difference launch without any specific dispatcher and launch with specific dispatcher?

```
var loading by mutableStateOf(false)

var errorMsg by mutableStateOf("")

private fun setLoading(isLoading: Boolean) {
    loading  = isLoading
}

fun signUp() {
  viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        signUpFirebaseUseCase.invoke(email, password).collect { result ->
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                when (result) {
                    is Response.Success -> {
                        setLoading(isLoading = false)
                    }
                    is Response.Loading -> {
                        setLoading(isLoading = true)
                    }
                    is Response.Error -> {
                        errorMsg = result.errorMessage
                        setLoading(isLoading = false)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you dont pass in any dispatcher, it will use what you have in your viewModelScope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Launching with Dispatchers.IO causes `signUpFirebaseUseCase.invoke` to be called on an IO thread, which is pointless since I assume it is not a blocking function. All it's doing is generating a Flow, so it shouldn't be blocking or suspending.

If you don't launch on Dispatchers.IO, then you're launching with `Dispatchers.Main.immediate`, the default for `viewModelScope`, so you could remove the `withContext` wrapper inside your `collect`.

The short answer is, if `signUpFirebaseUseCase.invoke()` correctly does not block, you do not need to mention any dispatchers anywhere in this code.

For more readable code, I recommend the `onEach`/`launchIn` pattern. It reduces nesting of code.

Comment: Just to add that if something in the producer of the flow actually needs to switch threads you can use `flowOn` rather than launch/ withContext and this probably should be done inside the use case or further up the chain.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't pass a `dispatcher` to launch, it will default to the dispatcher present in the context of the `CoroutineScope` in which you started that launch. If the coroutine context doesn't have a dispatcher, then launch will use `Dispatchers.Default`.

Reference: [Co-routines Launch](https://%20https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html)